# M1: Adding Configurable Products to Related Products not visible in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have a friend who has Magento 1 store based only on **Configurable Products**.

He came to me asking why Configurable Products added to other products in [**Related Products**], [**Cross-sells**] and [**Up-sells**] sections are not visible in frontend. I did a test and he is right. Magento is showing only simple products visible in frontend.

What shall I recommend in this case? Switching to Simple Products with Custom Options or there is something we don't know about using configurable products in those sections?

**Please Note:** cache is disabled and indexing was done after every changing so this is not the path to look into.

Answer (score 0):

What are the visibility settings for these `Configurable` and `Simple` products?

If you only want your catalog to show `Configurable` - set them to `Catalog, Search` & set `Simple` to `Not Visible Individually`. Flush cache, reindex, and check again.

Do the opposite if you want to use `Simple` products only, but this seems like a lot more work when updates are needed.

Comment: Visibility is set to Catalog,Search for all configurable products. All associated products to them are set to Not Visible Individually. We flushed the case, reindex and any configurable product is not appearing in Related, Up-Sells and Cross-Sells.

Comment: Can you update your original post with screenshots of the `Upsell`, `Related`, and `Cross-Sell` sku list? Were items added manually or do you have an extension running that is adding some for you?

Comment: It is a Magento default installation with sample pack. Do you own test to see Configurable Products cannot be used in Up-Sells, Related and Cross-Sells.

Comment: Yes, `configurable` products can be used in these related areas. I have them in my current multi-store and single store setup. Something about your configuration or product settings needs to be further examined.